# Why I can't upload MariaDB database into DropBox before shutdown or reboot?

Tags: bash, services

Every time before shutdown or reboot, to input `upload-dropbox` in my Debian 9 terminal in graph mode (non-login and interactive shell) can upload MariaDB database into my DropBox.

```
cat /home/debian9/.bashrc

$dir=$HOME/backup

ss-bwg(){
    /usr/bin/nohup /usr/local/bin/sslocal -c /etc/ss-bwg.json & 
}

backup(){
    USERNAME="xxxx"
    PASSWORD="xxxx"
    mysqldump -u root -pxyzzy wpdatabase > $dir/wp.sql.bak
}
upload-dropbox(){
    backup
    ss-bwg
    export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8118
    sudo service privoxy start
    cd $dir
    Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload  *  /
    sudo service privoxy stop
    unset https_proxy
    date >> $dir/dropbox.log
}
```

I want a smart way to do the job automatically.

```
sudo cat   /etc/systemd/system/upload.service

[Unit]
Description=Run command at shutdown
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target  
After=network-online.target  mariadb.service 

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/home/debian9/.bashrc
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/bin/bash  /home/debian9/upload.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

cat  /home/debian9/upload.sh
upload-dropbox

sudo systemctl enable upload
sudo systemctl start  upload
sudo reboot
```

To reboot and check upload's log info.

```
sudo journalctl -u upload
-- Logs begin at Fri 2018-02-02 10:27:08 HKT, end at Fri 2018-02-02 10:28:45 HKT
Feb 02 10:27:40 hwy systemd[1]: Started Run command at shutdown.
```

No error info in upload service's log.
No uploaded `wp.sql.bak` file in my DropBox.

How to fix it?

Comment: Variable assignments in scripts are done with `var=value`, not `$var=value`.  Run your script through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Major error:

```
$dir=$HOME/backup
```

should be remedied:

```
dir="$HOME/backup"
```

Further recommendation:

- double quote paths, e.g.:

  ```
  "$dir/wp.sql.bak"
  ```